# How do I use a Satnav (Garmin Nuvi 2599) in Turkey?

Tags: turkey, maps, gps-navigation

We have just got a new Garmin Nuvi 2599 for Christmas and may be going to Turkey next year.

The Nuvi 2599 comes with a full set of Europe maps that include Turkey.

I have tried to enter the address of a hotel we have used in the past, but looking at the map on the Nuvi 2599 it is showing a point a long way from the hotel. I entered the address using the postcode of the hotel.

Firstly how do address work in Turkey?

Then what is the best way to enter an address into the sat nav?

What level of mapping should I expect compared to UK?

Comment: Did you key in _only_ the postcode (and not the street name and number)? Then you will get instructions to somewhere reasonably central in the area covered by that postcode. Note that UK postcodes are unusually fine-grained geographically -- in most of the world they just denote the area served by one post office, and mail is sorted from there based on street names, etc.

Comment: @HenningMakholm,  is the street the fist or the last line of the address?

Comment: http://www.upu.int/fileadmin/documentsFiles/activities/addressingUnit/turEn.pdf

Comment: @MichaelHampton, would you like to convert your comments into a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Addresses work similarly in Turkey to most countries, in that a postcode is a general area. The point that your sat nav is showing will likely be the centre of that postcode area.

As Henning pointed out, however, that area may be quite large. Here in the UK, urban postcode areas are very small (a few houses) but out in the country they can take in a much larger area.

So in order to get accurate guidance, putting the street address in will be best. Michael's comment linked to a [useful document](http://www.upu.int/fileadmin/documentsFiles/activities/addressingUnit/turEn.pdf) explaining the address structure in Turkey. As you can see it is basically the same as here in the UK:

1. recipient’s name and surname.
2. organisation/legal person’s name.
3. sub-locality, village name or P.O box(PK) number.
4. street, position, building, site, floor, door name and/or number.
5. postcode, parish (district-town-municipality) or county or province name (if parish or 
   county names are not unique, province name should be specified).